# Smart minor mode toggle depending on major mode

Tags: init-file, hooks

I use several minor modes, which are enabled globally by default:

- `whitespace-mode`
- `linum-mode`
- `fci-mode`

I'm finding them very helpful when editing code sources and text files, however I does not want to activate them with some major modes, e.g. `dired-mode`, `eshell`.

I've tried to solve this as following:

```el
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook '(linum-mode 1))

(require 'whitespace)
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook '(whitespace-mode 1))

(require 'fill-column-indicator)
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook '(fci-mode 1))
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook '(fci-mode 1))
```

But this solution does not works well:

- reverting buffer toggles off `linum-mode`
- `whitespace-mode` not activating
- `fci-mode` not activating, producing error message

> File mode specification error: (invalid-function (fci-mode 1)) [2 times]
>   
>   What is the correct way to make smart toggle mentioned modes only with source code buffers and text buffers?

*P.S. A note about `fci-mode`: error message looks odd to me, because I can either use `M-x fci-mode` to toggle it, or evaluate `(fci-mode 1)` or `(fci-mode -1)`.*

Comment: What version of Emacs are you using?

Comment: @erikstokes `GNU Emacs 24.4.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0, Carbon Version 157 AppKit 1344.72) of 2015-02-05`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Emacs 23 `(some-mode 1)` was the typical way to turn on minor modes (but see this [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/10512/2274) for the proper way to add them to the hooks).  But Emacs 24 changed the rules for turning on minor modes.  The argument to mode functions is no longer needed to turn the mode on anymore:

> Toggle display of line numbers in the left margin (Linum mode).
>   With a prefix argument ARG, enable Linum mode if ARG is positive,
>   and disable it otherwise.  If called from Lisp, enable the mode
>   if ARG is omitted or nil.

So to simply turn on a minor mode, what you want is just `#'linum-mode` in your hooks.

Comment: @Malabarba, quite strange, because this works as expected without lambda and hash: `(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'whitespace-mode)`. BTW, what that `#` means?

Comment: @Geradlus_RU `'whitespace-mode` is fine. It is essentially the same as `#'whitespace-mode`. See this: http://endlessparentheses.com/get-in-the-habit-of-using-sharp-quote.html

Comment: @Geradlus_RU The code that is just plain wrong is: `(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook '(whitespace-mode 1))`

Comment: @Malabarba I have clarified the first sentence.

Comment: @Malabarba, thank you for good explanation article!

Answer (score 6):

A hook expects its entries to be ***functions***.  `(fci-mode 1)` is not a function.

What you want to use as a function is presumably `turn-on-fci-mode`, if that function exists, or `(lambda () (fci-mode 1))`, if not.

See the Elisp manual, node [`Defining Minor Modes`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Minor-Modes.html), particularly macro `define-globalized-minor-mode`.

You give no references for the global-mode functions you cite, so I don't know how they were defined.  But if they were defined using `define-globalized-minor-mode` then there is likely a `TURN-ON` function that you can use on a hook.

Comment: I've accepted **erikstokes**'s answer, however, your answer is very valuable too, because it solves issue with `fci-mode`. Voted up, thanks!

Comment: It's OK to accept a different answer. ;-) But be aware that you can change which one you like best (i.e., accept a different one) at any time. Tomorrow you might receive an answer that you find is better still.

Comment: I've defined global-mode function only for `fill-column-indicator` according to wiki: `(define-globalized-minor-mode global-fci-mode fci-mode (lambda () (fci-mode 1)))`. But now I've just followed your suggestion: `(add-hook 'text-mode-hook '(lambda () (fci-mode 1)))`

Comment: (Note: You do not need to quote `lambda` forms, and in fact it is not a good idea to do so.)